# Dll's referenced in class library project are not being copied

Tags: c#, dll, class-library

I have a solution which includes class library project and win forms app project. The thing is that when I try to run methods from class library that use third-party dlls (LeadTools to be specific), program crashes. When I check bin folder, I can see dll of class library project, but no third-party dlls, which should be there. How can I get this work?

Comment: there is an option in reference properties ``CopyToLocal``

Comment: Check the references for those DLLs in your project, specifically the "Copy to Output Directory" property to make sure it's set to 'always' or 'if newer'

Comment: Ensure you are adding all the DLLs as references. It will not be sufficient to only include that of your class library

Comment: CopyLocal is set to true. So you mean that I need reference same dlls in win form project? What's the point of having separate class library than?

Comment: @KorsaR Make sure you to set the build output path of your seperate class library to your main `WinForms` project.

Comment: It is also important have the proper architecture set. If the DLL you are referencing is for x86 only, your project's architecture must also match. By default, it is set to "Any CPU", try changing that to "x86" if it is not already.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov And what if several projects will use this class library?

Comment: @ForeverZer0, I did check this, both are set to x64

Comment: @KorsaR If it's a class library that you wrote, and all project compile to the same output dir, you should be fine. If each compile to its own, you have to make sure it's outputted to the proper folder.

Comment: Can you run in a debugger to see what the exception is?

Comment: @Yuval Correct me if I'm wrong. I thought that if I'm refererncing class library project from another project located in separate directory, all needed files should be automatically copied, which is not happening

Comment: @KorsaR If you're referencing them inside another project, you should be fine. I thought you were only referencing them in a class library which wasn't part of the winforms project.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'm referencing only class library project, not third-party dlls inside it

Answer (score 0):

In your class library project, add the third-party dll as a reference and make sure that on the reference properties the build action is set to copy to output directory.